# Error disconnecting Asterisk Manager

Tags: php, asterisk, agi

I am using Asterisk Manager to get events on incoming calls. I want to disconnect the Manager when a "Ring" event is received.

Below is my code which checks the "Ring" event upon receiving a call. My code disconnects the Manager, but also generates an error. Sometimes the error message appears multiple times.

What am I doing wrong?

```php
<?php

require_once('phpagi/phpagi.php');

function newstatus($ecode,$data,$server,$port){   

  if (!isset($data['ChannelStateDesc'])){
    $data['ChannelStateDesc'] = '';
  }    
  print_r($data);

  if ($data['Event'] == "Newchannel" && $data['ChannelStateDesc'] == "Ring") {    
    echo "Call Ringing!!!\n";    
    global $asm;    
    $asm->disconnect();
  }

}

$e = 'ENTERQUEUE';    
if ($e == 'ENTERQUEUE'){    
  $asm = new AGI_AsteriskManager();    
  $asm->connect();    
  $asm->add_event_handler("Newchannel", "newstatus");    
  $asm->wait_response(true);    
}
```

Error Message:

> PHP Warning:  fgets(): 9 is not a valid stream resource in /scripts/phpagi/phpagi-asmanager.php on line 158

Comment: how and where do you invoke this script?

Answer (score 1):

With `$asm->connect();` you open a socket,
with `$asm->disconnect();` you close the socket.

The Problem is, `disconnect` closes the socket in the eventcallback, but `wait_response` is a eventloop and the eventhandler get called again on a disconnected state.

If a request was just sent, wait_response will return the response. Otherwise, it will loop forever, handling events.

If you have remaining code, you could call that code (function) in the event handler (ie, new_status). If you want to do something on every event, you could register a wildcard event handler.

```
function newstatus($ecode, $data, $server, $port) 
{
    // ...
    echo "Call Ringing!!!\n";

    do_something($data);
    // ...no disconnect necessary
}


function on_all_events(...)
{
    // ...
}


function do_something($data)
{
    var_dump($data);
}


add_event_handler('*', 'on_all_events');
```

Comment: i have tried if($asm->connect()){ $asm->disconnect();} but same result. i need to read remaining code after wait_response, which i did not add here. therefore i cannot use $asm->disconnect(); exit; is there any way we can jump out of function over the wait_response after event receive and then disconnect the manager. Thanks

Comment: here is the example code, but there can be while loop which will be getting data from DB.

echo "I am Out after Disconnect\n";

Comment: Why do you want to close the connection? 
You can't do both disconnect and wait for further events.

Comment: I'd say don't disconnect, because you can't get a second ring event, or do you? If you really want to disconnect, than disconnect before you exit the script, because your script acts like a daemon and needs the connection, because you called `wait_response`.

Comment: after `wait_sponse`. If you want to disconnect earlier, you should disconnect if you also exit the script only.

Comment: i did but i got same message.

Comment: the message is clear, if you disconnect you loose your valid stream resource and that results in a error message, because you wait for further responses. Why do you disconnect **and** wait for response? Can you update your question and post your  code changes (where do you exit the script) and descibe how  you invoke your script?